# Private bytes for IIS Pool Increases Greatly after loading XMLs

Tags: c#, iis, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, datacontractserializer

```
            try
                {
                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePathAndName, FileMode.Open))
                    {
                        using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(fs))
                        {
                            using (XmlDictionaryReader xmlDictionaryReader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateDictionaryReader(xmlReader))
                            {
                                DataContractSerializer deserializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
                                obj = (T)deserializer.ReadObject(xmlDictionaryReader);
                                xmlDictionaryReader.Dispose();
                            }
                            xmlReader.Dispose();
                        }
                        fs.Dispose();
                    }
                }
```

Above mentioned code increases private bytes for my IIS pool by 300 MB. The number of files loaded are ~16,000 with an average size of 3 KB each. That's around ~60 MB of data causing an increase of 300 MB in memory.

Is there anything I am missing here which is causing the private bytes to balloon so much? Can I make it more efficient?

**Interesting observation**: I tried adding GC.Collect() right after all the files are loaded, it decreased the GC.GetTotalMemory(false) but did not affect the IIS APP POOL private bytes.

Comment: As usual, the answer here is: use a proper memory profiler, don't rely on process metrics to guess what's going on in your application. There's a VM to consider that has a mind of its own.

Comment: ... i.e. memory that is no longer in use by the application (and has been garbage collected) might not have been released by GC back to the system.

Comment: Does using `GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce; GC.Collect();` help?

Comment: @mjwills Nope, it doesn't.

Comment: @spender What memory profilers do you recommend? I am using DebugDiag and WinDbg but I guess I do not know how to spot irregularities.